# MVC4 query string to an Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got some problem with querystring building. I have a model:

```
[HttpGet]
 public partial class Task
    {
        public System.Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Priority { get; set; }
        public long TaskTypeId { get; set; }
        public TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
        public string GroupWorkspaceUrl { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Deadline { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PlannedHours { get; set; }
       {...}
    }
```

and I have 2 action in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult TaskCreate(string schemaType)
        {
            var model = new Task();
            model.Accept(_taskService.ReaderVisitor, schemaType)
             {...}
        }
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult TaskCreateWithModel(string schemaType, Task model)
        {
            SetDefaultValues(model);
            model.Accept(_taskService.ReaderVisitor, schemaType);
            {...}
       }
```

I'd like to build a query string from other C# WinForms solution that is call the second action in controller(public virtual ActionResult TaskCreateWithModel(string schemaType, Task model)) but I don't know how I send the Task model in query string? I tried to call this querystring: `http://localhost:82/Task/TaskCreate?schemaType=default&Description=someDesciption` but allways the first action is called. How can I build a query string with Task model?

Comment: What do you mean by: "_but allways the first action is calling_"?

Comment: You can't pass an `object` (in this case `Task`) as a parameter to an `HttpGet` action. Also,  your query string says `TaskCreate` if you want the second method to be called then it should be `TaskCreateWithModel`

Comment: http://localhost:82/Task/TaskCreate?schemaType=default&Description=someDesciption - that query string allways call the first(public virtual ActionResult TaskCreate(string schemaType)) action

Comment: changing to a POST will allow you to pass the object in the request body, and is the proper/standard/correct/best method for 'create' operations anyways

Comment: use the [HttpPost] with the same controller's Action name to make the action possible on form submission with query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unusual to create a new task resource using an HTTP GET operation. GETs are supposed to be idempotent (i.e. if you make the same request several times, the effect is just the same as if you made it once - no side effects)

Also using GET for create operations can make you liable to cross site request forgery (CSRF), since the ASP.Net MVC anti-forgery protection only works with POSTs.

A create operation would more usually be an HTTP POST (or maybe PUT), where the data for the task object is contained in the request body rather than the query string. Also using the query string restricts the amount of data you can have (2000 chars limit for a URL?).

If you use the HTTP POST method, then the automatic model binding of ASP.Net MVC will create the correct typed object from the request body so you will be able to have actions like

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult TaskCreateWithModel(string schemaType, Task model)
```

As you want, but with POST rather than GET and not using the query string. There is a good description of model binding in MVC here

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The name is clearly: QueryString. Everything you pass is interpreted as string (and you can unbox on server side).
Complex types cannot be passed by QueryString, except if you serialize it.

In your case, in particular, you need call:

```
http://localhost:82/Task/TaskCreateWithModel?schemaType=default&Description=someDesciption
```

To call the second Action.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this (with carriage returns for readability).
I guess the format of numbers and date will depend on your locale :

```
http://localhost:82/Task/TaskCreateWithModel?schemaType=default
                   &model.priority=3.2
                   &model.Description=hello
                   &model.GroupWorkspaceUrl=thisistheGroupWorkspaceUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a complex object as part of the GET request. You will either have to send a post request to the Controller/Action, or send individual properties as part of the GET request like jbl suggested. Personally, if it is possible, go for a POST request, since the querystring data wil be visible in the browser URL bar. You can encrypt it, but then browsers have URL length restrictions.